# how to download a stylized map from google cloud platform

Tags: javascript, android, json, google-maps

first of all I appreciate the interest given by my question and its possible answer, I continue.

I have a stylized map in Google Cloud Platform (V2) but I can't find a way to download the JSON or import it into Android or JavaScript, it would be helpful if you could guide me on how to implement it (by means of the ID) or where to download the JSON from , since, I have been able to use the V1 of the stylizer and it works for me in android if I import the generated JSON.

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/riMbC.jpg)

Thank you very much.

Comment: Does this help https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-sdk/cloud-based-map-styling ?

Comment: Thank you!, this is for Java/Kotlin but i need to for JavaScript :(. PD: I had not seen that documentation.

Comment: There is also documentation for JavaScript API: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/cloud-based-map-styling

Comment: Thank you!, please put your answers boton for close this question.